# Escaping characters on AzureBlobContent

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have got a problem to set my content in AzureBlobStorage.
In local, I have succeeded to replace characters for each files in a directory.

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\MyDirectory"
$targetFolder = "C:\MyDirectoryEncodeded"
$fileList = Dir $sourceFolder -Filter *.dat
MkDir $targetFolder -ErrorAction Ignore
ForEach($file in $fileList) {   
    $file | Get-Content | %{$_ -replace '"',''} | %{$_ -replace ',','.'} | Set-Content -Path "tempDirectory\$file"
    $newFile = Get-Content "tempDirectory\$file"    
    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines("targetDirectory\$file" , $newFile,$Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}
exit
```

But now, I need to do the same in Microsoft Azure.
I get the content into an Azure Blob Storage, I escape characters, I encoding my file in `UTF-8NoBom` and then I set the encode file into a new Blob Directory.

Nevertheless, I faced an issue when I want to set the new content with escape characters (First line in my loop).

```
$storageContext = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=<myAccountName>;AccountKey=<myAccountKey>;"
$sourceFolder = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "datablobnotencoded" -Blob "*.dat" -Context $storageContext
$targetFolder = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "datablob" -Context $storageContext 
MkDir $targetFolder -ErrorAction Ignore 
ForEach($file in $sourceFolder) {
    Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "datablobnotencoded" -Blob $file.Name -Context $storageContext | Get-AzureStorageBlobContent | %{$_ -replace '"',''} | %{$_ -replace ',','.'} | Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $file.Name -Context $storageContext -CloudBlob $file
    $newFile = Get-AzureStorageFileContent -Path $file 
    $Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
    [System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($file , $newFile, $Utf8NoBomEncoding)
}
```

I've got this error:

> Set-AzureStorageBlobContent : Cannot bind parameter 'CloudBlob'.
>   Cannot convert the 
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob"
>   value of type 
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Model.ResourceModel.AzureStorageBlob"
>   to type  "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob". At line:7
>   char:264
>   + ... lobContent -File $file.Name -Context $storageContext -CloudBlob $file
>   +                                                                     ~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-AzureStorageBlobContent], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId :  CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Commands.Storage.Blob.SetAzureBlobContentCommand

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Is this `... -Context $storageContext $targetFolder = ...` just a typo in the question? It should be on two separate lines or these lines should have been separated by a semicolon.

Comment: @Theo It's update, but not my main problem...

Comment: Are you getting valid folder paths in `$sourceFolder` and `$targetFolder` and should'n you be doing a `Get-ChildItem` (`Dir`) on the source folder first to iterate over the files in there?

Comment: Paths are correct because during debug I got the expected $file.Name.

Comment: Hello @TristanLeGall, do you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some mistakes in your powershell scripts:

1.You may misunderstand the usage of Get-AzureStorageBlobContent, it's used to download blob to local, you cann't get the content of the blob, more details refer [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azure.storage/get-azurestorageblobcontent?view=azurermps-6.13.0#description).

2.In the loop, you used `$newFile = Get-AzureStorageFileContent -Path $file`, the `Get-AzureStorageFileContent` cmdlet is for file share storage, not for the blob storage.

You can use `Get-AzureStorageBlobContent` to download the blobs to a local folder, then operate on the local file which is downloaded from blob storage. After the file is modified, you can use `Set-AzureStorageBlobContent` to upload the local files to the specified azure blob storage.

Sample code as below, and works fine at my side:

```
$context = New-AzureStorageContext -ConnectionString "xxxx"

#download the blobs in specified contianers
$sourceFolder_blob = Get-AzureStorageBlob -Container "test-1" -Blob "*.txt" -Context $context

#the target azure container, which you want to upload the modifed blob to
$taget_container="test-2"

#the local path which is used to store the download blobs, and make sure the folders exist before use.
$sourceFolder_local="d:\test\blob1\"
$targetFolder_local="d:\test\blob2\"

foreach($file in $sourceFolder_blob)
{

#download the specified blob to local path
Get-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container "test-1" -Blob $file.name -Destination $sourceFolder_local -Context $context

#get the local file path
$local_file_path=$sourceFolder_local + $file.name

#set content to the file in target local folder
$local_target_file_path = "$targetFolder_local"+$file.name


#since the files are downloaded to local, you can any operation for the local file
Get-Content $local_file_path | %{$_ -replace '-','!'} | %{$_ -replace ',','.'} | Set-Content -Path $local_target_file_path

$newFile = Get-Content -Path $local_target_file_path


$Utf8NoBomEncoding = New-Object System.Text.UTF8Encoding $False
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllLines($local_target_file_path , $newFile,$Utf8NoBomEncoding)

#the last step, upload the modified file to another azure container
Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -File $local_target_file_path -Context $context -Container $taget_container
}
```

Comment: Agree most part of the script, as Set/Get-AzureStorageblobContent, are to upload/download Blob to/from Local file, it WON'T ouput the content of the blob. But since the original question is to put the updated content to another blob, need add one line to the script: Set-AzureStorageBlobContent -Container $destContainerName -Blob $file.name -File $local_target_file_path -Context $context

Comment: @WeiWei-Microsoft, really did, see the last line of code.